# Ruby on Rails :serialize UTF8 problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, utf-8, yaml, serialization

When I serialize a hash containing UTF8 strings, like this:

```
  poll.variants = {0 => 'тест',1 => '-тест-',2 => 'test # test "тест'}
```

to an ActiveRecord field, the resulting field contains:

```
--- 
0: !binary |
  0YLQtdGB0YI=

1: !binary |
  LdGC0LXRgdGCLQ==

2: !binary |
  dGVzdCAjIHRlc3QgItGC0LXRgdGC
```

The utf8 strings get treated as binary and base64 encoded for some reason. The collation on the field is `utf8_general_ci`, and I'm a bit disappointed.

Is there any way to make ActiveRecord :serialize human-readable yaml to the field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to make ActiveRecord
>   :serialize human-readable yaml to the
>   field?

No. Its Base64 encoded so as to encode arbitrary text (in any encoding) down to the lowest common denonimator, which is then safe to send across the wire and/or store in datastores that dont accept UTF-8 data.

Comment: Oh, that's reasonable. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: The question is: Why doesn't Rails deserialize the string from the DB as UTF-8? It returns ASCII-8BIT...